# Add modal window after submitting form

Tags: html, node.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, modal-window

It's my second question today and I really want you to help again. I wrote a little program which contains a text field. When the user enters his phone number, I do some instructions to finally calculate a certain parameter and I want to show the final result of my program on a modal window just after clicking on the submit button. It's simple I think but I am really newer in programmation, that's why I find many difficulties. I wrote my program with node js (but no using template ! So the program is awful) but my question is mainly related to html I think. 
This my program :

```
var express = require('express'),
request = require('request'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

function createMainPage (req, res, msg) {

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
var result = '<html><head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>';
result += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">';
result += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">';
result += '<title> Demo </title>';
result += '</head><body><br /><br /><br /><div class="container">';
result += '<form class="form-horizontal" method="post"><fieldset><legend> Demo </legend>';
result += '<br /><h2><center>Please enter your Phone Number</center></h2> <br /> <br />';
result += '<div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">';
result += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputphonenumber" name="inputphonenumber"placeholder="+33XXXXXXXXX"></div>';
result += '</fieldset></div><br/><p style="text-align:center; font-weight:700; font-size:1.2em;">' + msg + '</dialog></p><br /><br /><br />';
//
//msg here is the parameter that i want to show on a modal windows after click on submit button
//
result += '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-6">';
result += '<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>';
result += '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></form>';
result += '<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>';

result += '</body></html>';
res.send(result);
}

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080)); // cannot force 80
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {createMainPage(req, res, "")
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
var myText = req.body.inputphonenumber;

//...... 
// I do some operations to finally get the parameter "message"
//......

createMainPage(req, res, customMessage);}

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('userDetails Node app is running on port',      
app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: What exactly is being asked here?

Comment: This is a bit unrelated, but you really should use templates, especially if you're already using Express. Doing so will prevent having to manually concatenate and render your output.

Comment: I was just asking how to add a modal windows in this code after clicking on submit button. In my previous code, you can see this line : 
result += '</fieldset></div><br/><p style="text-align:center; font-weight:700; font-size:1.2em;">' + msg + '</dialog></p><br /><br /><br />';

=> the parameter 'msg' is what I am talking about. What i can do so far, is to show it in the same window but I really need to show it on a modal window !. I hope it was clearer for you guys !

Answer (score 0):

I'd start simple without JS. When your form is submitted, render a page that just shows your parameter.

Then, add the modal markup to that page:

```
<div id="my_modal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After that, attach a jQuery submit listener to your form:

```
$('.form-horizontal').submit(function() {
  // do an AJAX get request for the page that's showing your parameter
  $.get(that_pages_url), function (data) {
    // set the modal's body to what the get request is returning
    $('#my_modal .modal-body').html(data);
    // show it
    $('#my_modal').modal('show');
  }

  // don't submit the form as normal, otherwise the user will be redirected
  return false;
});
```

Comment: can you just tell me please where exactly i should paste this code ? because i feel lost in my own html code since it's really unreadable

Comment: The modal markup goes in your `var result` in the `<body>` tag. You'd have to put the listener in its own .js file and call it with a `<script>` tag.

Comment: It's why I couldn't do that, my parameter was not global (it is defined as local after the instruction " app.post(......) ". What i did in my previous code is some operations to calculate this parameter and after that, I send the html code by the first method "createMainPage". So, if I create a new file, I can't access to this variable and I will not be able to use it. I know it's due to my bad code (because I don't know how to use templates). 
Do you have any idea how i can do that in the same file ?